# Require function is not defined

Tags: javascript, require, referenceerror

I am working on a 3D viewer using express.

My problem is that I am trying to require the file system module in one (not the main one) of my JS files. When I try to load the browser, the console  gives me the next message:

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

My project structure is:

- node_module
- src

  - js

    - app.js // the problem is here
  - views

    - index.ejs
- server.js

Comment: Browser know nothing about required - it's node.js functionality. You need to use import statement instead of require or bundle your scripts together with browserify or something like this

Comment: you could try import instead.. possible missing an "export" or even a "default" keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short example of how to use importing with the browser:

1. Create index.html with next content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Check script tag - we set type="module" - this instructs the browser that we are using module system

2. Create main.js script with:

```js
import name from './name.js';

console.log(name);
```

3. Create name.js file:

```js
const name = 'test';
export default name;
```

Now you need to run this app. The easiest way is to use [WebServer For Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb_)

Start the application and check the console. You should see that the 'test' is logged.

That's it. Please, keep in mind that this is just an example. We don't touch minification, caching and other important things.

Comment: @JoséEmilioBadíaValdés If it answers your question, feel free to mark the answer as resolved